# GCC - error while compiling

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I try to create an exe program, by compiling codes in assembler and C:

gcc -m32 aaa aaa.s aaa.c

And I get an error:

gcc: aaa : No such file or directory

In C file a only include stdio.h. I've read that the problem might be that gcc can't find this library, but i'm not sure if that's the case and even if so, what should I do to make it work?

Comment: What do you think every argument in `gcc -m32 aaa aaa.s aaa.c` means? Word for word.

Comment: first - name of executive program, second name of assembly file, third - name of C file

Comment: `gcc -m32 -o aaa aaa.s aaa.c`

Comment: and the "executive program" needs to be preceded by "-o"

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a flag to identify the output executable. Try

```
gcc -m32 -o aaa aaa.s aaa.c
```